# How to create and fill a list of lists in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-lists

I'm trying to populate a list with a for loop. This is what I have so far:

```
newlist = []
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        newlist.append(y)
```

and at this point I am stumped. I was hoping the loops would give me a list of 10 lists.

Comment: No, it will give you a list with 100 elements in it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You were close to it. But you need to append new elements in the inner loop to an empty list, which will be append as element of the outer list. Otherwise you will get (as you can see from your code) a flat list of 100 elements.

```
newlist = []
for x in range(10):
    innerlist = []
    for y in range(10):
        innerlist.append(y)
    newlist.append(innerlist)

print(newlist)
```

See the comment below by Błotosmętek for a more concise version of it.

Comment: …and anyway, `newlist = [[x for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]` is more concise.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this one line code with [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to achieve the same result:

```
new_list = [[i for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
```

Comment: It's probably neater to do `new_list = [list(range(10)) for _ in range(10)]` although mostly opinion based

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you only need one loop and append `range(10)`.

```
newlist = []
for x in range(10):
    newlist.append(list(range(10)))
```

Or

```
newlist = [list(range(10)) for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just nested list comprehension

```
[[x for x in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: This by itself won't do anything here. For someone who's struggling with two for loops (OP), you should probably add the important `new_list =` part... Also, it's probably neater to do `[list(range(10)) for _ in range(10)]`, although mostly opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

You should put a intermiate list to get another level

```
newlist = []
for x in range(10):
    temp_list = []
    for y in range(10):
        temp_list.append(y)
    newlist.append(temp_list)
```