# how to create nested list of dictionaries from XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, nested-loops

This XML sample represents a sample Metabolite from the [HMDB](https://hmdb.ca/downloads) the `Serum Metabolites` dataset.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hmdb xmlns="http://www.hmdb.ca">
<metabolite>
  <version>4.0</version>
  <creation_date>2005-11-16 15:48:42 UTC</creation_date>
  <update_date>2019-01-11 19:13:56 UTC</update_date>
  <accession>HMDB0000001</accession>
  <status>quantified</status>
  <secondary_accessions>
    <accession>HMDB00001</accession>
    <accession>HMDB0004935</accession>
    <accession>HMDB0006703</accession>
    <accession>HMDB0006704</accession>
    <accession>HMDB04935</accession>
    <accession>HMDB06703</accession>
    <accession>HMDB06704</accession>
  </secondary_accessions>
  <name>1-Methylhistidine</name>
  <cs_description>1-Methylhistidine, also known as 1-mhis, belongs to the class of organic compounds known as histidine and derivatives. Histidine and derivatives are compounds containing cysteine or a derivative thereof resulting from reaction of cysteine at the amino group or the carboxy group, or from the replacement of any hydrogen of glycine by a heteroatom. 1-Methylhistidine has been found in human muscle and skeletal muscle tissues, and has also been detected in most biofluids, including cerebrospinal fluid, saliva, blood, and feces. Within the cell, 1-methylhistidine is primarily located in the cytoplasm. 1-Methylhistidine participates in a number of enzymatic reactions. In particular, 1-Methylhistidine and Beta-alanine can be converted into anserine; which is catalyzed by the enzyme carnosine synthase 1. In addition, Beta-Alanine and 1-methylhistidine can be biosynthesized from anserine; which is mediated by the enzyme cytosolic non-specific dipeptidase. In humans, 1-methylhistidine is involved in the histidine metabolism pathway. 1-Methylhistidine is also involved in the metabolic disorder called the histidinemia pathway.</cs_description>
  <description>One-methylhistidine (1-MHis) is derived mainly from the anserine of dietary flesh sources, especially poultry. The enzyme, carnosinase, splits anserine into b-alanine and 1-MHis. High levels of 1-MHis tend to inhibit the enzyme carnosinase and increase anserine levels. Conversely, genetic variants with deficient carnosinase activity in plasma show increased 1-MHis excretions when they consume a high meat diet. Reduced serum carnosinase activity is also found in patients with Parkinson's disease and multiple sclerosis and patients following a cerebrovascular accident. Vitamin E deficiency can lead to 1-methylhistidinuria from increased oxidative effects in skeletal muscle. 1-Methylhistidine is a biomarker for the consumption of meat, especially red meat.</description>
  <synonyms>
    <synonym>(2S)-2-amino-3-(1-Methyl-1H-imidazol-4-yl)propanoic acid</synonym>
    <synonym>1-Methylhistidine</synonym>
    <synonym>Pi-methylhistidine</synonym>
    <synonym>(2S)-2-amino-3-(1-Methyl-1H-imidazol-4-yl)propanoate</synonym>
    <synonym>1 Methylhistidine</synonym>
    <synonym>1-Methyl histidine</synonym>
  </synonyms>
  <chemical_formula>C7H11N3O2</chemical_formula>
  <smiles>CN1C=NC(C[C@H](N)C(O)=O)=C1</smiles>
  <inchikey>BRMWTNUJHUMWMS-LURJTMIESA-N</inchikey>
<diseases>
    <disease>
      <name>Kidney disease</name>
      <omim_id/>
      <references>
        <reference>
          <reference_text>McGregor DO, Dellow WJ, Lever M, George PM, Robson RA, Chambers ST: Dimethylglycine accumulates in uremia and predicts elevated plasma homocysteine concentrations. Kidney Int. 2001 Jun;59(6):2267-72.</reference_text>
          <pubmed_id>11380830</pubmed_id>
        </reference>
        <reference>
          <reference_text>Ehrenpreis ED, Salvino M, Craig RM: Improving the serum D-xylose test for the identification of patients with small intestinal malabsorption. J Clin Gastroenterol. 2001 Jul;33(1):36-40.</reference_text>
          <pubmed_id>11418788</pubmed_id>
        </reference>
      </references>
    </disease>
</diseases>
```

What I'm trying to do is to run a nested loops and create a list of dictionaries.

Every dictionary will represent one metabolite.

Each of the keys in a dictionary will be selected nodes (by tags name).

The values of the keys will be either list of strings or a single string.

This is the structure I think is needed (better ideas are also welcome):

```
[  
    {
    "accession":"accession.value", 
    "name": "name.value",
    "synonyms":[synonyms.value.1, synonyms.value.2, synonyms.value.3,... ], 
    "chemical_formula":"chemical_formula.value", 
    "smiles": "smiles.value",
    "inchikey":"inchikey.value", 
    "biological_properties_pathways":[pathways.value1, pathways.value2, pathways.value3,.. ]
    "diseases":[disease.name.1, disease.name.2, disease.name.3,.. ]
    "pubmed_id's for disease.name.1":[pubmed_id.value.1, pubmed_id.value.2, pubmed_id.value.3,... ]
    "pubmed_id's for disease.name.2":[pubmed_id.value.1, pubmed_id.value.2, pubmed_id.value.3,... ]
    .
    .
    .
    }, 
    {"accession":"accession.value", 
    "name": "name.value",
    "synonyms":[synonyms.value.1, synonyms.value.2, synonyms.value.3,... ], 
    "chemical_formula":"chemical_formula.value", 
    "smiles": "smiles.value",
    "inchikey":"inchikey.value", 
    "biological_properties_pathways":[pathways.value1, pathways.value2, pathways.value3,.. ]
    "diseases":[disease.name.1, disease.name.2, disease.name.3,.. ]
    "pubmed_id's for disease.name.1":[pubmed_id.value.1, pubmed_id.value.2, pubmed_id.value.3,... ]
    "pubmed_id's for disease.name.2":[pubmed_id.value.1, pubmed_id.value.2, pubmed_id.value.3,... ]
    .
    .
    .
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

This is what I did so far

```
# Import packges
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

# load data 
data1 = et.parse('D:/path/to/my/Projects/HMDB/DataSets/saliva_metabolites/saliva_metabolites.xml')

# create name space 
ns = {"h": "http://www.hmdb.ca"}

# extract the first 3 metabolites only for easy work
metabolites = root.findall('./h:metabolite', ns)   [0:3]
```

Now running the nested loop on the 3 metabolites and select specific nodes (the first 2 I needed) as dictionaries.

```
newlist = []
for child in metabolites:
    innerlist = []
    dicts = {}
    for subchild in child:
        if subchild.tag=='{http://www.hmdb.ca}accession':
            dicts={"accession":  subchild.text}
        if subchild.tag == '{http://www.hmdb.ca}name':
            dicts = {"name": subchild.text}
            innerlist.append(subchild.text)
            print(innerlist)
    newlist.append(dicts)
```

I received this output:

```
>> print(newlist)
[{'name': '1-Methylhistidine'}, {'name': '2-Ketobutyric acid'}, {'name': '2-Hydroxybutyric acid'}]
```

instead of

```
[{'accession': 'HMDB0000001','name': '1-Methylhistidine' },
 {'accession': 'HMDB0000005', 'name': '2-Ketobutyric acid'},
 {'accession': 'HMDB0000008', 'name': '2-Hydroxybutyric acid'}]
```

meaning the `<name>`  surpasses `<accession>`.

Also tried to enter a list as values for a key

```
newlist = []
for child in metabolites:
    innerlist = []
    dicts = {}
    for subchild in child:
        # if subchild.tag=='{http://www.hmdb.ca}accession':
        #     dicts={"accession":  subchild.text}
        # if subchild.tag == '{http://www.hmdb.ca}name':
        #     dicts = {"name": subchild.text}
        if subchild.tag == '{http://www.hmdb.ca}synonyms':
            for synonym in subchild:
                dicts = {"synonyms": synonym.text}
                print(synonym.text)
            innerlist.append(subchild.text)
            print(innerlist)

    newlist.append(dicts)

            innerlist.append(subchild.text)

        newlist.append(innerlist)
```

And the output again is surpassed:

```
>> print(newlist)
[{'synonyms': '1-Methylhistidine dihydrochloride'},
 {'synonyms': 'alpha-Ketobutyric acid, sodium salt'},
 {'synonyms': '2-Hydroxybutyric acid, monosodium salt, (+-)-isomer'}]
```

Each of the 3 keys above contains the **last** values from each list, instead of a list of values.

should have received something like that (but with all values per synonym):

```
>> print(newlist)
[{'synonyms': ['(2S)-2-amino-3-(1-Methyl-1H-imidazol-4-yl)propanoic acid',
               '1-Methylhistidine',
               ....
               '1-Methylhistidine dihydrochloride' ]},

 {'synonyms': ['2-Ketobutanoic acid',
               '2-Oxobutyric acid',
                ....
               'alpha-Ketobutyric acid, sodium salt']},

 {'synonyms': [ '2-Hydroxybutanoic acid',
                'alpha-Hydroxybutanoic acid',
                ....
                '2-Hydroxybutyric acid, monosodium salt, (+-)-isomer']}
]
```

I was using those questions to write the loop:

1. [Create List of Dictionary Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492656/create-list-of-dictionary-python)  - I think is very similar but can't make it work
2. [How to create and fill a list of lists in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502482/how-to-create-and-fill-a-list-of-lists-in-a-for-loop)
3. [Python ElementTree - iterate through child nodes and text in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174152/python-elementtree-iterate-through-child-nodes-and-text-in-order)
4. [Populating a dictionary using for loops (python) [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280856/populating-a-dictionary-using-for-loops-python)
5. [Generating nested lists from XML doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007042/generating-nested-lists-from-xml-doc)

Any thoughts, hints, clues or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try, [`xmltodict`](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) package ?

Comment: Have been trying it but in my case, only a few nodes are needed (about 12-14) per metaboltie, and that's is why turned to this method using conditioned loops

Comment: Serious question: why bother with the conversion? Why not just use the native xml?

Comment: @ Jack Fleeting, I'm quite new to Python and XML so weren't familiar with it. Did you mean to native XML _database_ in "native xml"? I read now but not sure yet what it is and how it works. Thank You  @ Jack Fleeting.

Comment: You can either move to an xml database like BaseX, or - staying with python - use a library like lxml, which supports xpath. In both bases, you can zero in on a particular item using xpath. For example, `//metabolite//synonyms/synonym[3]` will output `Pi-methylhistidine`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first code snippet is probably reassigning the new dictionary to the variable dict:

```
newlist = []
for child in metabolites:
    innerlist = []
    dicts = {}
    for subchild in child:
        if subchild.tag=='{http://www.hmdb.ca}accession':
            dicts={"accession":  subchild.text}
        if subchild.tag == '{http://www.hmdb.ca}name':
           # here the old value of dict is overriden with new value
            dicts = {"name": subchild.text}
            innerlist.append(subchild.text)
            print(innerlist)
    newlist.append(dicts)
```

You should probably use assignment in form dict[key] = value:

```
newlist = []
for child in metabolites:
    innerlist = []
    dicts = {}
    for subchild in child:
        if subchild.tag=='{http://www.hmdb.ca}accession':
            dicts["accession"] =  subchild.text
        if subchild.tag == '{http://www.hmdb.ca}name':
            dicts["name"] =  subchild.text
            innerlist.append(subchild.text)
            print(innerlist)
    newlist.append(dicts)
```

Similar problem seems to be also with the second code snippet:

```
newlist = []
for child in metabolites:
    dicts = {}
    innerlist = []
    for subchild in child:
        if subchild.tag == '{http://www.hmdb.ca}synonyms':
            for synonym in subchild:
                innerlist.append(synonym.text)
    dicts["synonyms"] = innerlist

    newlist.append(dicts)
```

But (as it was already pointed out) you could use some more convenient libraries instead of parsing XML manually.

Here is merged script:

```
newlist = []
for child in metabolites:
    dicts = {}
    innerlist = []
    for subchild in child:
        if subchild.tag=='{http://www.hmdb.ca}accession':
            dicts["accession"] =  subchild.text
        if subchild.tag == '{http://www.hmdb.ca}name':
            dicts["name"] =  subchild.text
        if subchild.tag == '{http://www.hmdb.ca}synonyms':
            for synonym in subchild:
                innerlist.append(synonym.text)
            dicts["synonyms"] = innerlist
    newlist.append(dicts)
   
print(newlist)
```

It outputs following result:

```
[{'accession': 'HMDB0000001', 'name': '1-Methylhistidine', 'synonyms': ['(2S)-2-amino-3-(1-Methyl-1H-imidazol-4-yl)propanoic acid', '1-Methylhistidine', 'Pi-methylhistidine', '(2S)-2-amino-3-(1-Methyl-1H-imidazol-4-yl)propanoate', '1 Methylhistidine', '1-Methyl histidine']}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! The two script works great. I'd like to ask another question if Ok. I'm trying to join two scripts you wrote into one, but I don't understand  why in the first one the `innerlist.append(subchild.text)` comes after    assigning the values the the dictionary ( `dicts["name"] =  subchild.text`) , while in the second script  `innerlist.append(synonym.text)` comes before it (before `dicts["synonyms"] = innerlist`).

Comment: I updated answer with the merged script. Generally in script 1 innerlist is needed for debugging purposes only, in the second one innerlist gathers synonyms.